# Trying to count the amount of objects created

Tags: java

I keep getting 0 for both counters before and after creating x amount of objects.

```
class Thing {
    private static int count = 0;
    
    public Thing() {
        count++;
    }
    
    public static int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}

public class getCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = Thing.getCount();
        
        System.out.println("Objects created: " + counter);

        Thing thing1 = new Thing();
        Thing thing2 = new Thing();
        
        System.out.println("Objects created: " + counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using the same variable (which is just once computed). call getCount in your last println and you should get the latest count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `getCount()` again to get an updated count. If you cache it in a variable you'll always have the same value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Objects created: " + Thing.getCount());

    Thing thing1 = new Thing();
    Thing thing2 = new Thing();
    
    System.out.println("Objects created: " + Thing.getCount());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on John's correct answer and explain - *why* his answer is correct:

Assignment of the value to the variable, is *storing that value in that variable* at a particular time of execution.

For example:

```
int x = Math.sqrt(25);
```

Means to store the value returned by `Math.sqrt(25)` (which is 5), into variable `x`.

You store the value returned from `getCount()` in the local variable `counter`, but you never update it, and disregarding of how many objects you'll create, if `counter` variable remains like it is, it will always have the same value `0`.

After your constructor updates the class member `counter` twice, you might want to call `getCount()` again to retrieve the up to date value.

Comment: clear as day! great explanation and thank you again!